# Erro de "untrusted domain" ao tentar conectar-se ao Banco de Dados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, banco-de-dados

Ao tentar conectar ao banco de dados, recebo o seguinte erro:

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used
>   with Windows authentication.

Estou utilizando MVC 5 e abaixo segue minha `connectionstring`. Não estou utilizando *Windows authentication*, mas por algum motivo o sistema está considerando como se eu estivesse utilizando.

> add providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data
>   Source=123.456.789.10;Initial Catalog=NomeDoBanco;Integrated
>   Security=True;Persist Security Info=True;Connect Timeout=30; User
>   ID=Foo; Password=Bar" name="DefaultConnection"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seta `Integrated Security=False;`

> Quando false, ID de usuário e senha são especificados na conexão.
>   Quando true, os atuais credenciais da conta do Windows são usados
>   ​​para autenticação. Valores reconhecidos são true, false, yes, no, e
>   SSPI (altamente recomendável), o que equivale a verdadeira . Se o ID
>   do usuário e senha são especificados e Segurança Integrada é definida
>   como true, o ID de usuário e senha serão ignorados e Segurança
>   Integrada será usado.

Fonte: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=VS.100).aspx).